# Slide Show in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Does anyone knows a plugin that can be used in asp.net for slideshow Or any code that could be used to get the slideshow ?

I actually have all my image path in a database and I need a next and previous button to navigate through images.

I also need to show two images at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of beautifull slideshows in jquery: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/04/jquery-image-slider-slideshow-plugin-examples.html

Because it is on jquery, it is compliant with asp.net :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to do this through this link:

Comment: @user4340844 perfect :-) Please consider to validate one answer if it supply your needs.

Comment: :I have use the JQUery Cycle plugin:http://line25.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-image-slideshow-with-jquery-cycle

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code that you can slide show images with interval 5 seconds. 
You can embed your img in modal window

```
var runFunction = true;
var i = 1;

screenShotArray = [
    "/Content/1.png",
    "/Content/2.png",
    "/Content/3.png"
];

var myTimer = null;

function slideShow() {


    myTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (runFunction !== false) {
            $("#screenShots img").prop("src", screenShotArray[i++]);
            i = i % 3;             
            slideShow();
        }
    },
    5000
    );        
}

function stopSlideShow() {
     clearTimeout(myTimer);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually have all my image path in my database and I need a next and previous button to navigate through images.

Comment: You could use simply $("#screenShots img").prop("src", 'yourImage.png'); on button click event

Comment: how to I navigate through pictures by using next and previous button?

Comment: Something like `$("#myNextButtonId").on("click", function(){ $("#screenShots img").prop("src", 'nextImage.png'); })` or adapt code above

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been able to do this through this link:http://line25.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-image-slideshow-with-jquery-cycle